# display a long string in a table row

Tags: iphone

i have a tableview which displays the result from the web service
the result fron the web sevice is in form of string array, where each string in the array is pretty long. It is like "1|123|JP Morgan|111|2000.0|Pending", similarly there are strings which i diplay in each row of the table.
but as you can see the string is very long, to display it in a single table row.
in the table view, i can just view first 3 ie "1|123|JP Morgan" the it shows.....

how can i display the entire string  in the table

Answer (score 2):

Your options are to make it smaller or make a custom table cell. To change the size, set the property `cell.textLabel.font` to a font of a smaller size (e.g. using `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10]`. You may also want to change `cell.textLabel.numberOfLines` to something greater than 1.

To see more about making custom cells, read the [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `UILabel` to your cell's `contentView`.  If you do this, you can set the `UILabel.numberOfLines` to a number greater than 1.  If you set it to 0, it will use as many lines as needed.

Comment: how do i increase the labels at runtime, like i dont know, what would be the result coming from the web service.

Comment: Set numberOfLines to 0.  It will expand as needed then, to fill the frame you've set.